# Package TikZ error compile

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-external

I got this error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/arrow right' and I am goi
ng to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.187   \end{tikzcd}
```

And this is the part of the code when the error appears:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= (a).base]
        \node[scale=1.3] (a) at (0, 0){
        \begin{tikzcd}
        U\arrow[arrow left]{drr}{\phi \ \circ \ \pi_{y}}
        \arrow[arrow right]{dr}[description]{\phi}
        \arrow[dotted]{ddr}[description]{\phi \ \circ \ \pi_{x}} & & \\
                                                                 & W \arrow{r}[swap]{\pi_{y}} \arrow{d}{\pi_{x}} & Y \arrow{d}[swap]{g} \\
                                               & X \arrow{r}{f} & Z
187.-      \end{tikzcd}
      };
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

I put the number '187' because that is the line of the error for that you can notice, maybe I missing a library.. but if it's so.. I don't know which it is.

Comment: Do you have `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` in your preamble? I can't test it right now.

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, I have it. The error says about 'arrow left' and 'arrow right', I have no idea why...

Comment: Have you tried `rightarrow` or `leftarrow`? I think this is the correct command.

Comment: @Alenanno, thanks a lot! you just save my year.. happy new year 2016, btw.

Comment: No problem, happy new year! :)

Comment: For future reference, a line number for an error is only useful if we have a complete example so that when we compile it we get that same error. The code you post should produce the error you want help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace those commands with `rightarrow` and `leftarrow`, which are the appropriate ones, like

```
\arrow[rightarrow]...
```